# Reading LiveDeviceID.xml for password

Tags: c#, xml, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to connect to CRM Dynamics On-line and I can get there if I runt the following command from the console in order to get the user name and the password.

```
deviceregistration.exe /operation:show
```

It'll be, obviously, much nicer if I can read the XML containing the information programmatically. However, the contents of the file are horribly encrypted, looking like this.

```
<Data version="1">
  <User username="1kz9u5e4t4br4nah8sm61coc" type="Logical">
    <Pwd>
      AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAASLr2v6+hUU2goUw2ivLu9AAAAAACAAAAAAA 
      QZgAAAAEAACAAAABvPcbpZtXzDjyRoQAm19c71KA3J6TpyU0rieu4WY/1OgAAAAAOgA
      AAAAIAACAAAAAT5Aunf6PBWDRp7UPKYrcP33tniAfAHf1MzEjcUAvVKSAAAAArJkRAv
      Ml+cgNy8fUscH//u41scGezSw+OOvOkpn86r0AAAADLmCwYMLVw+Qo5hPwxnlawMW7s
      0fvMJJkM1UiyfBQ49nJOF7v0pa32DtFFluDsjGv4Yddj7j+FtNiYNxmvzc0l
    </Pwd>
  </User>
</Data>
```

How do I get to the real data using C#? Please note that I know how to access the file, read its contents and process the XML structure obtaining the two strings of interest. It's **getting from the encrypted version to a plain one** that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRM SDK contains file sdk\samplecode\cs\helpercode\deviceidmanager.cs. This file should be helpful if you want to connect Dynamics CRM On-Line.

```
    ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
    credentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
    credentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
    credentials.UserName.Password = password;

    IServiceManagement<IOrganizationService> orgServiceManagement = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IOrganizationService>(new Uri(organizationUrl));

    AuthenticationCredentials authCredentials = new AuthenticationCredentials();
    authCredentials.ClientCredentials = credentials;
    authCredentials.SupportingCredentials = new AuthenticationCredentials();
    authCredentials.SupportingCredentials.ClientCredentials = Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceIdManager.LoadOrRegisterDevice();
    AuthenticationCredentials tokenCredentials = orgServiceManagement.Authenticate(authCredentials);
    var organizationTokenResponse = tokenCredentials.SecurityTokenResponse;

    OrganizationServiceProxy _serviceProxy;
    IOrganizationService _service;
    using (_serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgServiceManagement, organizationTokenResponse))
    {
        _service = (IOrganizationService)_serviceProxy;

        WhoAmIResponse response = (WhoAmIResponse)_service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest());
        Console.WriteLine(response.UserId.ToString());
    }
```